# VSCode eslint is not using local config with vue3

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, eslint, create-vue

I just scaffold a new Vue project using `npm init vue@latest`, I have the eslint extension installed on VSCode and out of the box it is highlighting that many errors(even in .eslintrc.cjs) coming from the boilerplate code.

- Terminal errors
  [image: Terminal erros]
- `.eslintrc.cjs`
  [image]
- `package.json`
  [image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, but the actual code in text (formatted as code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-vue` does not scaffold a Prettier config, so default Prettier options are used. I agree it's surprising to discover linter warnings in scaffolded code, and I've [reported the issue](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue/issues/116).

### Workaround

Most of the linter warnings are regarding [quotes](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quotes) and [semicolons](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#semicolons).

You can copy [`create-vue`'s Prettier config](https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue/blob/afddba9/.prettierrc) (i.e., create `<projectRoot>/.prettierrc`) to align with the codebase:

```json
{
  "semi": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "trailingComma": "none"
}
```

Then, either restart the IDE, or restart its ESLint server to pick up the new config:

1. Open the [command palette in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/command-palette) by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on macOS, or <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows.
2. Enter `>` followed by `ESLint: Restart ESLint Server`.

The other errors are easily fixed by running this command from a terminal:

```bash
npm run lint
```

Comment: but why would they ship something obvious like this?

Comment: I saw your pr, guess no need to report the issue